# How to make joe editor start from the very first line on commits?

Tags: joe

I upgraded the system (to openSUSE 15.3) and I noticed that now when I commit something using git or svn, when I am about to enter some comment (I set joe as editor) the caret is not placed at the very first line, but at the first comment made by git/svn.

I don't like this behaviour, so how can I make joe to put caret in the first line?

**Update** Git example. After issuing "git commit", editor is launched and I can add comment here. This is actual result (it is just the beginning of commit text):

```
|# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
```

And this is what I would expect (and it worked this way previously):

```
|
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
```

"|" here denotes cursor/caret, it is not an actual character. The first line is an empty one.

**Update 2** snv, again showing just begining. Actual behaviour:

```
|--This line, and those below, will be ignored--
```

Expected/previous behaviour:

```
|
--This line, and those below, will be ignored--
```

**Update 3**:  I tested mcedit against both svn and git, in both cases I got behaviour as expected -- i.e. caret/cursor was placed in very first line. Ad I leave it this way (i.e. mcedit as editor) and today, after several successful commits, mcedit also shown the file with cursor/caret in the second line (so incorrectly).

Comment: How do you set `joe` as the editor? Does this also happen with e.g. `vim`? What do you mean by caret (`^`)?

Comment: @they, EDITOR variable is set to joe. I didn't test vim, I don't how to work with it, and anyway I couldn't tell for odd behaviour. Here at least I know how it worked previously and how it works now. Caret = text cursor. When you start typing, the text appears at the cursor/caret, and while typing it moves along.

Comment: I deleted my comment about `git` default behavior because it was wrong.  I tested with  `mg`, `nano`, `emacs`, `vim`, and `joe`, and they all put the cursor on line 1 of the temporary file.  If you use a different editor, where does it put the cursor?

Comment: Putting the carrer on the first line is a default behaviour, however, if you type `editor +2 file` (where editor is emacs, vi or others), the `+2` tells the editor yo put the cursor on the second line. I don’t know how `git` launch the editor.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer, thank you for the info. So I took a peek at running processes when I executed "git commit" and copied the file as well. I noticed two things, git executes editor with just filename as parameter. When editing commit for git, the editor started from the second line (incorrect), but when I executed it by hand using the copied file it start from the first one. I even changed the name to COMMIT_EDITMSG to mimic everything, still same input, two different behaviours.